# Add Custom field in carousel slider wordpress

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

I just need to add the custom fields (5 custom fields in my custom post type named PORTFOLIO) in carousel slider wordpress.

I googled it but i can't find any carousel slider which allow me to add the custom field in carousel slider.

How can i do this?

Comment: Use ACF plugin and add as many custom fields as you want

Comment: I already used ACF, but how can i add that custom fields in carousel slider?

Comment: There must be slug/post-type for your carousel. Find that slug and add your custom fields from ACF settings to that slug

Answer (score 1):

To add custom meta field in custom post type (e.g: portfolio)
you can follow this tutorial
[Tutorial to add meta box in custom post type.](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/03/adding-custom-post-types-fields-and-taxonomies-in-wordpress/)

Thanks